# Compiz not working on old Dell latitude Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: compiz

I recently upgraded a old Dell Latitude c610 and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it. I installed Compiz with the settings manager, plugins , etc. I enabled 3D cube, wobbly windows added New burn effect to window minimize etc and none of it works. I've went through troubleshooting made sure Unity plugin is enabled etc. Nothing. No wobbly windows, no burn effect no cube. Is it because this laptop is old? Please dont guess and say yes only facts please. Here are the specs:

```
Intel Pentium III-M 1.0 GHz
Memory 512.0 MB / 1.0 GB (max)
Hard Drive 80.0 GB
Operating System Ubuntu 12.4
Display Type 14.1 in TFT active matrix Integrated
Max Resolution 1024 x 768 ( XGA )
Graphics Processor AGP 4x - ATI Mobility Radeon
Optical Drive CD-ROM - Plug-in module
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the hardware requirements for compiz as Wikipedia says:

> Compiz works on the standard X.Org Server, by using AIGLX. Besides Intel GMA graphics cards, AIGLX also supports using **AMD graphics cards (including R300 and newer cards) using the open-source radeon driver which supports GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap** since fall 2006.[...]**ATI/AMD's binary drivers do since version 8.42.**

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz#Hardware_requirements.

Also you can see: [Lowering Compiz memory usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82684/how-to-lower-compiz-memory-usage).