# Compiz using excessive amounts of RAM?

Tags: ram

So I've been running Ubuntu 16.04 on my new build, and I have 16gb of ram.
What I've noticed in Htop is that for some reason over the course of a few hours compliz starts eating up ram before maxing out around 2gb.

I can't tell if it's a memory leak or if it's just compliz using what's available.
Anyone else with high ram available seeing increased usage from compliz?

Theres 5-10 instances ranging from 80mb to 400mb each.

Comment: See [Lowering Compiz memory usage](https://askubuntu.com/q/82684)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 16GB of ram and ubuntu 16.04 and i don't have this issue.

Maybe you have some extra compiz plugins enabled.

you can reset your compiz config to the default by running this command

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```